# RSS re-sync automation with Wordpress & FeedBurner

Tags: wordpress, rss

I am working on a **wordpress** site and configured my `RSS` feed with **FeedBurner**. Whenever I'm publishing a post, it's immediately send to My RSS feeds. If any typo found out later, I need to login to FeedBurner to *re-sync* it.

My Questions on this are,

1. Is there any automated way to enforce a sync at Feedburner if I publish a post again?

*OR*

2. Is there any way to have a separate publish only for RSS? ie, I'll do that after all my proof reading is completed.

*OR*

3. Is there any way to delay publishing a post to RSS from the actual time I really publish the post?

Answer to any question is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your 1st option will work out, Feedburner never had a resin api, AFAIK. Moreover Feedburner APIs are deprecated  now.

Comment: Thanks @Biju, for your answer and comment. Answer, let me try it out. About your comment, is there any possibility for 2nd option, say by adding a `RSS Publish` button in **Quick Edit** or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice you to go with the 3rd option, which works for me for ages.

add following to your `functions.php`

```
function publish_later_on_feed($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $now = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $wait = '3'; // value for wait;
        $device = 'HOUR'; //MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR
        $where .= " AND TIMESTAMPDIFF($device, $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt, '$now') > $wait ";
    }
    return $where;
}
```

and don't forget to add filter.

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'publish_later_on_feed');
```

See [WP Engineer post](http://wpengineer.com/320/publish-the-feed-later/) as well, for more details.